# How to Connect a MIDI Keyboard in Bluestacks android

Tags: bluestacks

Is there a way to recognise and use a USB MIDI keyboard (Akai mpk mini) with Bluestacks (Android VM for Windows)?

My Android devices recognise the MIDI keyboard correctly but Bluestacks does not.

Comment: I don't have any experience in using a USB MIDI keyboard on Android, but I remember on some Android devices (possibly [Android 6.0 Marshmallow and above](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/midi)), the Developer options allow changing the USB configuration to MIDI. Also, could you [edit] and mention what you have tried to let us know and prevent suggesting the same attempts?

Comment: In my android phone it works correctly, in bluestacks vm it doesn't...

Comment: found a solution yet?

Comment: no i havent, but i use my phone and tablet with it